# AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

I am trying to call some java method in `OnAudioFilterRead` function body.

Here is the code segment.

```
void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
{
    AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread();
    if (ok)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            obj = new AndroidJavaObject("com.xx.aop.media.av.GPUFrameCapturer");
            Debug.Log(obj.Call<bool>("isRecording"));
        }
    }
}
```

When I build apk on Android platform.

Always encountered this error.

> 06-13 15:20:51.981 20255-20388/com.MeiTu.XRay E/Unity:
>
> AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find
>   class "com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper" on path:
>   DexPathList[[directory "."], nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper" on path: DexPathList[[directory
>   "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib,
>   /vendor/lib]]

Comment: Most likely your dependencies are not properly declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnAudioFilterRead` function is called in another `Thread` so it looks like you used `AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread()` to make it possible to use `AndroidJavaObject` from another Thread. You also need to detach it. Call `AndroidJNI.DetachCurrentThread()` at the end of the `OnAudioFilterRead` function:

```
void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
{
    AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread();
    if (ok)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            obj = new AndroidJavaObject("com.xx.aop.media.av.GPUFrameCapturer");
            Debug.Log(obj.Call<bool>("isRecording"));
        }
    }
    AndroidJNI.DetachCurrentThread()
}
```

---

If this doesn't work, initialize the `AndroidJavaObject` outside the `OnAudioFilterRead` function such as the `Start` or `Awake` function then use it in the `OnAudioFilterRead` function like above.

```
AndroidJavaObject obj;

void Start()
{
    obj = new AndroidJavaObject("com.xx.aop.media.av.GPUFrameCapturer");
}

void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
{
    AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread();
    if (ok)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            Debug.Log(obj.Call<bool>("isRecording"));
        }
    }
    AndroidJNI.DetachCurrentThread()
}
```

Comment: Tanks a lot, This is really the solution for me .

Comment: If so, please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the check-mark icon next to the answer. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) will show you how to do so.

Comment: Sorry where is the check-mark icon... I can not find it.